# Square brackets after pointer declaration/reference

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, declaration, implicit-conversion

I am porting code from C to Go, and have encountered something in C I've never seen before. I like to think of myself as being pretty competent and self sufficient when it comes to searching out and learning about new concepts like this, however in this case I have been absolutely unable to do so.

The code I'm porting is declaring and referencing (what I think) are pointers, but they are surrounded by parenthesis and then indexed with square brackets. Some examples:

Struct definition

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t *S;
    uint32_t (*S0)[2], (*S1)[2], (*S2)[2];
} example;
```

Assigning values:

```
ex.S0 = (uint32_t (*)[2])ex.S;
ex.S1 = ex.S0 + (1 << someInt1) * someInt2;
ex.S2 = ex.S1 + (1 << someInt1) * someInt2;
```

As is, the naming, declaration and use aren't enough for me to formulate a search that will tell me more. So, for S0, S1, and S2, what are they, and where can I learn more about declaring and using them?

Comment: These are pointers to arrays

Comment: What does the [2] in the declaration signify?

Comment: The pointer points to an array of 2 elements

Comment: So, in effect, S0 is pointing to two elements within S?

Comment: I would rather say they are arrays of pointers. So the variable S is a pointer to one or many uint32_t but S0, S1 and S2 are each arrays of two pointers. A pointer usually points to the first of possibly more elements of something.

Comment: For instance, `(*ex.S0)[0]`, or equivalently `ex.S0[0][0]`, will yield `ex.S[0]`.  `(*ex.S0)[1]` or `ex.S0[0][1]` yields `ex.S[1]`.  But `ex.S0[1][0]` yields `ex.S[2]`.  In essence it allows you to treat `ex.S` as a two-dimensional array.

Comment: @Henrik Carlqvist: ```uint32_t (*S0)[2]``` makes ```S0``` a pointer to an array of two ```uint32_t```. ```uint32_t *(*S0)[2]``` would be a pointer to an array of pointers.

Comment: Yes, @sj95126, but probably more to the point would be that an array of two pointers to `uint32_t` would be spelled `uint32_t *S0[2]`.  In the example declarations, it is exactly the function of the parentheses to yield the former (pointer to array) instead of the latter (array of pointers).

Comment: Whoops, my bad, as John said, the parantesis around (*S0) is the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you had a two-dimensional array:

```
uint32_t array[][2] = {
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4},
    {5, 6},
    {7, 8},
    {9, 10},
    {0, 0}
};
```

We know that this isn't *really* a "two-dimensional" array.  It's really an array of arrays.  `array` is an array of somethings, and what each something is is a little array of two `uint32_t`'s.  So `array[0]` is an array of two `uint32_t`'s, `array[1]` is an array of two `uint32_t`'s, etc.

Suppose that, for some reason, you wanted to manipulate pointers to rows in this array.  Perhaps you want to move down the array using code like this:

```
sometype p;
p = array;
while(p is not at the end of array) {
    do something with the array pointed to by p;
    p++;
}
```

Or suppose you wanted to keep track of certain rows in the array, again via pointers:

```
sometype row2, row4;
row2 = &array[2];
row4 = &array[4];
```

We know that this makes sense, because `array` is an array of something, so `array[2]` is the second (really the third, because 0-based) something, ao `&array[2]` is a pointer to that something.  And, again, in this case the "something" is an array of two `uint32_t`'s.

But the question is, what is `sometype`?  We want `p`, `row2`, and `row4` to have type "pointer to array of two `uint32_t`".  This is an unusual type, but it does exist, and it's the type you've been asking about:

```
uint32_t (*p)[2];
```

This says that `p` is precisely a pointer to an array of two `uint32_t`'s.  The big and obvious subquestion, of course, is: what the heck are those parentheses doing around the `(*p)` part?  And the answer is that without them, we'd have

```
uint32_t *p[2];        /* not what we want */
```

and this would declare `p` as an array of two pointers to `uint32_t`.  In C, there are precedence relationships in declarations just like there are in expressions, and `[]` binds more tightly than `*`.  So if you want to say that `p` is a pointer first (and that what it's a pointer to is any array), you need the parentheses:

```
uint32_t (*p)[2];
```

So now we can rewrite that loop I wrote earlier that tries to scan the array:

```
uint32_t (*p)[2];
p = array;
while((*p)[0] != 0 || (*p)[1] != 0) {
    printf("next row: %d, %d\n", (*p)[0], (*p)[1]);
    p++;
}
```

This works, and I encourage you to compile and run with it.  There are some more "funny" parentheses, again because of precedence.  Our `p` is indeed a pointer to a little array of two `uint32`'s.  So `(*p)` *is* an array of two `uint32`'s.  So `(*p)[0]` is the first element of the pointed-to array, and `(*p)[1]` is the second.  But without the parentheses we'd have `*p[0]` and `*p[1]`, and those would try to, basically, treat `p` as an array first and a pointer second, which is not what we want.  (Actually, as @sj95126 and I are discussing in the comments, a notation like `*p[1]` *does* work — at first I was thinking it would be an error — but it does something different, namely to access the `[0]` element of the subarray one past `p`, not the `[1]` element of the array at `p`.)

Finally, it may be useful at this point to observe that for "complicated" types such as pointers to arrays, C's `typedef` mechanism can sometimes make things clearer.  Earlier I wrote, as pseudocode,

```
sometype p;
```

because we weren't quite sure what type to use.  But, now that we know, and if we wanted more convenient declarations for variables like `p`, `row2`, and `row4`, we could write

```
typedef uint32_2 (*sometype)[2];
```

This is just like our earlier declaration of `p`, except that it has that extra keyword `typedef` out at the front.  This changes things: we are not declaring "`sometype`" as a pointer to an array of two `uint32_t`'s; we are instead declaring "`sometype`" as an *alias* or shorthand for the type, "pointer to an array of two `uint32_t`'s".  We can then literally say things like

```
sometype p;
```

or

```
sometype row2, row4;
```

The typedef only helps when declaring `p`, `row2`, and `row4`, though.  Down in the expressions where we use them, we'll still need the extra parentheses.  And typedefs incorporating pointers can also be confusing (more confusing than they're convenient, that is), so many programmers recommend avoiding pointer typedefs.  (Also of course "`sometype`" is a horrible name, in practice.  If you really wrote this you'd want something like `typedef uint32_2 (*ptrary2)[2]; ptrary2 p;`.)

For a bit more discussion on pointers to arrays, see [question 6.13](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrtoarray.html) in the old [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: So what would a *real* 2D array be?

Comment: @JohnBollinger It's not a point I'm adamant about, but theoretically a "real" 2D array would be declared as `uint32_t arr[M, N]`, and you'd index it as `arr[i, j]`, and it wouldn't necessarily be possible to manipulate pointers to its rows.  (But, as I say, I'm not a pedant abut this; most of the time I'm perfectly happy to refer to an array of arrays in C as a "multidimensional array", because it certainly acts well enough like one.)

Comment: I just ran this under a debugger to confirm: ```(*p)[0] = 3``` and ```*p[1] = 7``` correctly populate an array, without any compiler warnings. In gdb, ```print *p``` shows ```{3, 7}```. Either syntax seems to work in this case, though that may not be true for more complex forms.

Comment: @sj95126 That sounds like an error.  `p` is a pointer, so ordinary pointer arithmetic applies, so`p[i]` basically accesses another row.  And since that row is an array, and since arrays decay to pointers to their first element, `*p[i]` ends up accessing the first element (that is, `[0]`) of the array pointed to by `p`.  And in particular, `*p[1]` should access the first element of the row one after `p`, not the second element of the row at `p`.

Comment: @Steve Summit: I checked two environments: Linux (x86_64) with gcc 10.3 and Cygwin with gcc 10.2. ```(*p)[0] = 3``` and ```*p[0] = 3``` both generate exactly the same assembly instructions.

Comment: @sj95126 Sure, for `p[0]`.  Now try `(*p)[1] = 3` versus `*p[1] = 3`.

Comment: @Steve Summit: D'oh, right :) And now I see my earlier mistake. When I was testing some things, I set ```*p[0]``` and ```(*p)[1]``` (not ```(*p)[0]``` and ```*p[1]```) and that combination produced the expected result, because ```*p[0]``` and ```(*p)[0]``` are equivalent for index 0. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @sj95126 But your momentary confusion pointed out an oversight in my thinking and a mistake in my answer (now corrected), so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Brackets are part of the grammar for a *declarator*. They denote arrays.

In C, a *declaration* is a list of *declaration-specifiers* followed by a list of *declarators* with optional initializations.

The *declaration-specifiers* specify a type like `int`, `double`, `long long`, `struct foo`, or a typedef name. (They also include additional kinds of specifiers like `extern` and `inline`, which are not of consequence in this answer.) Whatever type `T` this is, the declarators then specify things that have the type `T`.

Declarators have several forms:

- A plain name, `D`, says `D` has the type `T`.
- A declarator in parentheses, `(D)`, means the expression `(D)` has the type `T`, which means `D` also has type `T`, so this has the same meaning as a plain name in a declarator. However, it groups the declarator for further parsing.
- A declarator with brackets, `D[expression]`, means  the expression `D[i]` will have the type `T`, which means `D` must be an array of the type.
- A declarator with an asterisk, `*D`, means the expression `*D` will have the type `T`, so `D` must be a pointer to `T`.
- A declarator with parentheses, `D()`, means the expression `D()` will have the type `T`, which means `D` must be a function that returns `T`.

These forms can be combined. A declarator `(*D)[]` says `(*D)[]` has type `T`, so `(*D)` is an array of `T`, so `*D` is also an array of `T`, so `D` is a pointer to an array of `T`.

Essentially, a declarator is a picture of how a name will be used in expressions, and the actual type of the name is figured out by working backwards from what the type of that expression is.

(There are additional parts of declarators not discussed above, such as parameter lists for functions and some options for the contents of brackets when declaring arrays.)

Answer (score 2):

This

```
uint32_t (*S0)[2], (*S1)[2], (*S2)[2];
```

is a declaration of pointers to the array type `uint32_t[2]`.

For example if you have a two-dimensioanl array like this

```
uint32_t a[N][2];
```

where `N` is some (unimportant in this case) value then you can declare a pointer to the first element of the array like

```
uint32_t ( *p )[2] = a;
```

The array designator `a` used as an initializer is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. Elements of the array are one-dimensional arrays of the type `uint32_t[2]`.

Or if you have a one-dimensional array like

```
uint32_t a[2];
```

then a declaration of a pointer to the array can look like

```
uint32_t ( *p )[2] = &a;
```